# How to make ojdbc specific code database independent while compilation

Tags: java, oracle, db2

I have the below method:

```
public static void testBlob(String targetDatabase, Blob blob)
{
        if("ORACLE".equals(targetDatabase))
        {
            if(blob instanceof oracle.sql.BLOB)
            {
                //perform some operation
            }
        }
    }
```

This piece of code exists in my application which supports both Oracle as well as DB2. What I want is when this application needs to be used for DB2 database, I want it to build  without ojdbc jar (**I have a restriction here, as the application being used with DB2 database, my users are not ready to use ojdbc jar**). Is there any way to make this piece of code generic?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably is a simpler way of doing this, but you could try something like

```
if(blob.getClass().isInstance(Class.forName("oracle.sql.BLOB").newInstance())) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried with the above code snippet. I got the below exception (GenericSql  is my class): 

`java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.java.sql.GenericSql can not access a member of class oracle.sql.BLOB with modifiers "protected"
 at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.java.sql.GenericSql.testBlob(GenericSql.java:24)
 at org.java.sql.GenericSql.main(GenericSql.java:13)`